# How to get position of last, non-empty child of given element

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XML which has been exported from Excel, and I need to transform it (using XSLT1.0) into another XML that Adobe InDesign can read. I already have been able to split into different tables and to produce an acceptable XML, that InDesign easily reads. I need now to specify the maximum number of non-empty cells per each row on a given table, or - more easily - provide the position of the last, non empty cell on a given row.

By now, I've been using the following code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(Row[2]/Cell/*[not(*)])"></xsl:value-of>
```

which returns the number of non-empty cells on the second row of each table (which is always the longest row in a table). The problem is that sometimes I need to skip the first or the second column to keep things aligned, so e.g. instead of having a value of 3 i get a value of 2.

Here's the xml i need to parse:

```xml
<Table name="Configs">
   <Row>
    <Cell StyleID="s73"><Data Type="String">Configs</Data></Cell>
    <Cell StyleID="s73"/> <!-- this must be empty AND visible -->
    <Cell StyleID="s73"/> <!-- this must be empty AND visible -->
    <Cell StyleID="s64"/> <!-- this must be REMOVED in final xml -->
    <Cell StyleID="s64"/> <!-- this must be REMOVED in final xml -->
    <Cell StyleID="s62"/> <!-- this must be REMOVED in final xml -->
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell StyleID="s62"><Data Type="String">This</Data></Cell>
    <Cell StyleID="s62"/> <!-- this must be empty AND visible -->
    <Cell StyleID="s64"><Data Type="String">That</Data></Cell>
    <Cell StyleID="s64"/> <!-- this must be REMOVED in final xml -->
    <Cell StyleID="s64"/> <!-- this must be REMOVED in final xml -->
    <Cell StyleID="s62"/> <!-- this must be REMOVED in final xml -->
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell StyleID="s62"><Data Type="String">A1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell StyleID="s62"><Data Type="String">B1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell StyleID="s64"><Data Type="String">C1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell StyleID="s64"/> <!-- this must be REMOVED in final xml -->
    <Cell StyleID="s64"/> <!-- this must be REMOVED in final xml -->
    <Cell StyleID="s62"/> <!-- this must be REMOVED in final xml -->
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell StyleID="s62"><Data Type="String">A2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell StyleID="s62"><Data Type="String">B2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell StyleID="s64"><Data Type="String">C2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell StyleID="s64"/> <!-- this must be REMOVED in final xml -->
    <Cell StyleID="s64"/> <!-- this must be REMOVED in final xml -->
    <Cell StyleID="s62"/> <!-- this must be REMOVED in final xml -->
   </Row>
   </Table>
```

And this is (part of) the XSL I'm using

```xml
<xsl:if test="count(Row) &gt; 1">

    <xsl:attribute name="Id:tcols" namespace="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/">
        <!-- <xsl:value-of select="count(Row[2]/Cell/*[not(*)])"></xsl:value-of> -->
        <xsl:value-of select="count(Row[2]/Cell/*[not(*)])"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:variable name="columns-in-table" select="count(Row[2]/Cell/*[not(*)])"></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each select="Row">


            <xsl:for-each select="Cell">
                <xsl:if test="position() &lt; $columns-in-table + 1">
                    <xsl:element name="Cell">
                        <xsl:attribute name="Id:table" namespace="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/">cell</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="Id:crows" namespace="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/">1</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="Id:ccols" namespace="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/">1</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Data"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:element>                                                      <!-- /Cell -->
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>                                             <!-- /select Cell-->


    </xsl:for-each>                                     <!-- /select Row-->

</xsl:if>
```

What I need to get is:

```xml
    <Table xmlns:Id="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" Name="Configs" Id:table="table" Id:trows="4" Id:tcols="3">
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1">Configs</Cell>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1"/>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1"/>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1">This</Cell>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1"/>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1">That</Cell>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1">A1</Cell>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1">B1</Cell>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1">C1</Cell>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1">A2</Cell>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1">B2</Cell>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1">C2</Cell>
    </Table>
```

What I instead get is:

```xml
    <Table xmlns:Id="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" Name="Configs" Id:table="table" Id:trows="4" Id:tcols="2">
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1">Configs</Cell>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1"/>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1">This</Cell>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1"/>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1">A1</Cell>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1">B1</Cell>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1">A2</Cell>
      <Cell Id:table="cell" Id:crows="1" Id:ccols="1">B2</Cell>
    </Table>
```

Comment: I think only Change:


<xsl:if test="position() &lt; 4">

Comment: $columns-in-table would is returning the wrong number of columns too, since it uses the exact same code for Id:tcols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:variable name="columns-in-table" select="count(Row[2]/Cell[*][last()]/preceding-sibling::Cell) + 1"/>
```

Comment: I was struggling with using "preceding sibling" etc, but couldn't get to this point. This solution indeed works. Thank you